# So Popular, What am I?

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme

Pursued by many, hated by few,
It's amazing how much I can do.
Creation, enlargement, or despise,
Tell me now where you keep your eyes.
Life or death, on different fronts,
I am the goal of many hunts.
All may have, and all seem to want,
But in different ways, now don't flaunt.
I may be the beginning, or maybe the end,
So riddle out what I am my friend.

Hint 1:

> Some of my previous riddles were interpreted on a "naughtier" side, so I decided to go with that idea and make this one more on that side.

Comment: You mean, other than Austin Powers?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are

> breasts

Pursued by many, hated by few,

> Men usually love breasts.  Even many women like having them, although a few may not.

It's amazing how much I can do.

> That's why they're called "weapons of mass distraction".

Creation, enlargement, or despise,

> Creation = create lust in men, or create milk.  Enlargement = implants.  Despise = breast reduction surgery.

Tell me now where you keep your eyes.

> Many men stare at them.

Life or death, on different fronts,

> Breasts feed (and therefore help give life to) babies.  Breast cancer can cause death (credit to Sabre for that).

I am the goal of many hunts.

> Many men want to touch them.

All may have, and all seem to want,

> All women have them, and many women want larger ones.

But in different ways, now don't flaunt.

> Some women show them off, other women are more modest.

I may be the beginning, or maybe the end,

> Beginning as in foreplay, end as in the, *ahem*, climax. (credit to Sabre for this one)

Comment: You've got it! See if you can fill in the remaining clues.

Comment: I was thinking about this, but couldn't make enough of the clues fit >_< Maybe death = cancer?

Comment: If we go really naughty, the last line could be foreplay vs money shot...

Answer (score 6):

Pursued by many, hated by few,

> Beauty

It's amazing how much I can do.

> Beauty can influence people and accomplish much...

Creation, enlargement, or despise,

> Plastic surgery

Tell me now where you keep your eyes.

> You are looking at my new assets!

Life or death, on different fronts,

> Beauty can fade and die

I am the goal of many hunts.

> Many people continue to seek it.

All may have, and all seem to want,

> Most people appreciate beauty.

But in different ways, now don't flaunt.

> But it is also in the eye of the beholder.

I may be the beginning, or maybe the end,

> Beauty can come to you at different points in life (physical and otherwise)

So riddle out what I am my friend.

> Beauty.

Comment: +1 Getting close. You are on the right track. The item in question can a perform/create creation, enlargement, and despise, rather than having it done to it.

Comment: so it's an item, characteristics/emotions and other non touchable things are incorrect? or am I taking that to literal?

Comment: Don't want to give too much away, but some of the clues might point one way or the other.

Answer (score 4):

I'll take a shot, although some of the lines are a bit of a stretch...

Pursued by many, hated by few,

> Sex is a universal drive

It's amazing how much I can do.

> Tons of ways to have sex, and many reasons and outcomes

Creation, enlargement, or despise,

> Procreation, erections (or pregnancy), angry sex

Tell me now where you keep your eyes.

> Not sure... maybe sexual orientation (i.e. who you like to look at)

Life or death, on different fronts,

> Procreation vs raping-to-death?

I am the goal of many hunts.

> The goal of many a college student's Friday night, for starters...

All may have, and all seem to want,

> Anyone can have sex (barring disease and whatnot), and in modern culture it seems to be very important to everybody

But in different ways, now don't flaunt.

> People want different kinds of sex (fetishes), sex should be private

I may be the beginning, or maybe the end,

> First time vs breakup sex

So riddle out what I am my friend.

> Sex

Comment: This could be it, given the hint!

Answer (score 3):

I think it can be

> Wealth

Pursued by many, hated by few,

> Many want it, few don't.

It's amazing how much I can do.

> Richness usually means power.

Creation, enlargement, or despise,

> Some of its effects...

Tell me now where you keep your eyes.

> People are attracted by opulence.

Life or death, on different fronts,

> There's physical richness and spiritual wealth.

I am the goal of many hunts.

> Prizes

All may have, and all seem to want,

> There's money for everyone, if well distributed

But in different ways, now don't flaunt.

> Flaunting isn't a good way to show your wealth.

I may be the beginning, or maybe the end,

> You can born rich, or die rich.

Comment: +1 Definately a nice approach. Not what I was going for though. All do have this item, whereas there are definately those that do not have wealth.

Answer (score 3):

To riddle you back I'll give it a lob, as for my guess I think you're:

> A job

Pursued by many, hated by few,

> Many people want a job to make money, some hate their jobs.

It's amazing how much I can do.
Creation, enlargement, or despise,

> Jobs help in progressing society (or possibly making it worse) and are created, grow and shrink

Tell me now where you keep your eyes.

> Possibly where your occupation is

Life or death, on different fronts,

> People can often give up their 'life' for a job

I am the goal of many hunts.
All may have, and all seem to want,

> People hunt for jobs and want one to earn money/a living

But in different ways, now don't flaunt.

> Don't flaunt your job to others

I may be the beginning, or maybe the end,

> maybe the beginning of a career, end of all your free time :)

So riddle out what I am my friend.

P.S I notice I didn't riddle an answer, but at least it rhymed!

Comment: +1 I love the rhyme as the first part of the answer. Not there though. "All" do not have a job. All may want, but not all have.

Answer (score 3):

My guess

> Intelligence

Pursued by many, hated by few,

> Many strive to be smarter, some despise those who are smarter than themselves

It's amazing how much I can do.

> By gaining knowledge, you can do more

Creation, enlargement, or despise,

> Create ideas, gain knowledge, despise (emotion)

Tell me now where you keep your eyes.

> Always moving forward, looking for new opportunities to understand

Life or death, on different fronts,

> In the pursuit of knowledge, many can die if not careful how they obtain it.

I am the goal of many hunts.

> Again, striving for a fuller understanding

All may have, and all seem to want,

> A certain level of intellect, many try to gain more...

But in different ways, now don't flaunt.

> Don't show off your intellect, it is becoming of you

I may be the beginning, or maybe the end,

> Without it, we cease functioning or we're merely floating along in space

So riddle out what I am my friend.

> Intelligence

My other guess:

> "Focus", but I wasn't sure how to answer the parts of the riddle with it just yet.

Comment: +1 I like it, but unfortunately no. I had to drive to work this morning, and that reaffirms in my mind that not everyone has intelligence.

Answer (score 2):

Pursued by many, hated by few,

> Many people want love, just some hate it, mainly when jealous.

It's amazing how much I can do.

> Love can break down mountains is the saying? i know there's some saying but you get the point.

Creation, enlargement, or despise,

> love creates opportunities, en enlarges someone's world, some people despise those who have found love.

Tell me now where you keep your eyes.

> though i found this one difficult i think: when in love you keep your eyes on the person/object which has inspired your love?

Life or death, on different fronts,

> Love can bring life (babies), love can bring death (crime passionel).

I am the goal of many hunts.

> many see getting love as a hunt, they want to obtain it.

All may have, and all seem to want,

> evryone can love someone/something and evryone seems to want love?

But in different ways, now don't flaunt.

> I had to look up the word Flaunt, +1 for expanding my vocabulary :P
>  Some people parade their love in the faces of others though some would say you don't parade your own happinesses in the faces of others.

I may be the beginning, or maybe the end,

> love can be the beginning of many things but can also be the end (of a loveless life for example)

So riddle out what I am my friend.

> you are Love

Comment: Newlines are your friend. :)

Comment: got it, i clicked on edit by an other post to figure it out xD well.. at least i'm learning a lot today :P

Comment: +1 Very nice. Not what I was looking for, but it fits really well. I would point out that the lines "All may have,... Flaunt" are tied together. Try to find something that fits with that.

Answer (score 1):

As second attempt, I try:

> Clothes

Pursued by many, hated by few,

> There people who spend their lives doing shopping, and there are nudists.

It's amazing how much I can do.

> You protect from cold, sun, wind, physical damages...

Creation, enlargement, or despise,

> They can be designed. They can be even enlarged, if needed. Finally, an ugly shirt can be despised! (The NASA guy, eheh!)

Tell me now where you keep your eyes.

> You keep them on clothes, theoretically you should...

Life or death, on different fronts,

> Even deads have clothes!

I am the goal of many hunts.

> Shopping! Discounts!

All may have, and all seem to want,

> Everyone can afford clothes, even the very poor

But in different ways, now don't flaunt.

> It's not a good habit to make a show of your clothes.

I may be the beginning, or maybe the end,

> You dress clothes from birth until death.

Comment: Any time you feel the need to write "I'm not racist, btw", you may want to reword.

Comment: Yeah, just in case I changed it to "poor." I like these thoughts too, but still not there. Clothes can be created, enlarged, or despised, but can't do it themselves.

Answer (score 1):

Pursued by many, hated by few,

> Life

It's amazing how much I can do.

> Life is everywhere, diverse (extremophiles)

Creation, enlargement, or despise,

> Life creates, grows..

Tell me now where you keep your eyes.

> Eyes of life can be in many places, different forms.

Life or death, on different fronts,

> Hmm, maybe it's birth?

I am the goal of many hunts.

> Most people want to keep living, live longer.

All may have, and all seem to want,

> Everyone is alive.

But in different ways, now don't flaunt.

> People have different lives.

I may be the beginning, or maybe the end,

> Life is a circle, circle of life.

So riddle out what I am my friend.

> Life.

Comment: +1 I really like this, but not it doesn't fit with life or death. Great on the others though!

Answer (score 0):

Youth or eternal Life?

You can't hate it because you had it and lost it. You always want it back. It is almost universally considered the apex of beauty and human aesthetics.

Love this puzzle. Thank you for sharing!!! Can't wait for the answer 8-D

Comment: The answer's already been posted :P Nonetheless you're on the right track.