# An ungodly creation - What am I?

Tags: riddle

It starts off as a creation of God,
followed by a godly creation.
Having them together is odd,
but between them is a one way affection.

A disgusting symbol of disparity
between wealth and poverty.
Yet it is an irony
as a proof of gender equality.

Hint:

> The answer is a term with 2 words

Hint #2:

> Half of the population will mostly agree on "**a godly creation**. "

Hint #3:

> It also make sense to replace 'Gender equality' with 'Gender Inequality'

Comment: I challenge the close voter to come up with another answer that fits!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try 2 after the hint:

> Man boobs

It starts off as a creation of God,

> Again, man created by god.

followed by a godly creation.

> Most men probably think breasts are sent from heaven.

Having them together is odd,

> Man boobs are not the norm, though I can't say too much :-(

but between them is a one way affection.

> Men love boobs. Boobs don't really love men.

A disgusting symbol of disparity
 between wealth and poverty.

> Those with a lot of wealth can buy bigger boobs, or clothing items that show them off.  Also, someone may be "well endowed" with big boobs. From the OP, those that are wealthy often can afford more food (and weight used to be a symbol of wealth), so wealthy men are more likely to have man boobs.

Yet it is an irony
 as a proof of gender equality.

> Women (almost) always have boobs, men often don't. Definately some inequality there. Plus, a lot of men treat women differently because of their boobs.

Comment: There we go!  I was looking for wealthy people (male, since it's man boobs) which symbols by a big body for the second last hint

Comment: @Alex Very nice.

Comment: I have the idea after seeing your post http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/12085/so-popular-what-am-i

Answer (score 3):

The answer is

> "man made"

It starts off as a creation of God, followed by a godly creation.

> Man was created by god, but when men create things it can be godly

Having them together is odd, but between them is a one way affection.

> Men love the things that they make, but the creations can't love back

A disgusting symbol of disparity between wealth and poverty.

> All wealth and poverty derives from what man has made.

Yet it is an irony as a proof of gender equality.

> We say "man"-made to denote things made by both men and women. In this context, it means "human," not "male."

Comment: You're correct on half of the answer.  Check out Hint #2

Comment: Hmm...that's what hinted me at "man" in the first place. I'm not really sure where to go from here.

Comment: Man can have affection to many things; something are somehow more popular in particular

Answer (score 1):

Is it:

> Garden of Eden?

It starts off as a creation of God,

> The garden of Eden is a creation of God

followed by a godly creation.

> God is said to have created the human

Having them together is odd,

> The humans are not perfect but the garden is (or the garden + adam and eve = 3, which is an odd number)

but between them is a one way affection.

> Not sure about this one

A disgusting symbol of disparity
between wealth and poverty.

> Garden of Eden = wealth . The rest is poverty

Yet it is an irony
as a proof of gender equality.

> Eve ate the apple but both Adam and Eve were excluded from the garden.

Comment: good guess but not this

Answer (score 1):

It could be

> **Yin and Yang**
>  [image]

It starts off as a creation of God,
followed by a godly creation.

> According to Wikipedia, God created Tai-Chi, which subsequently split in Yin and Yang.

Having them together is odd,
but between them is a one way affection.

> They're opposite, you can't have both at the same time (at least not completely).

A disgusting symbol of disparity
between wealth and poverty.

> Indeed it's a symbol of disparity, and wealth and poverty are opposites!

Yet it is an irony
as a proof of gender equality.

> Male and female are just two "shades" of Yin and Yang.

*Note: I'm not Taoist and my information could be inaccurate, but this is what I understood reading this [topic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yin_and_yang) in Wikipedia.*

Comment: Liked the way you approach with the answer, but nope that's not it.

Answer (score 1):

It could be

> Man cave

It starts off as a creation of God,

> it can be said natural cave are created by God.

followed by a godly creation.

> Man cave, on the other hand is created by man. And most men would agree it's a godly creation.

Having them together is odd,

> Man and cave do not usually come together.

but between them is a one way affection.

> Man loves his man cave, but cave does not love man.

A disgusting symbol of disparity
between wealth and poverty.

> Only man with decent amount of money ca build their own man cave.

Yet it is an irony
as a proof of gender equality.

> Women is welcomed in the man cave, but they usually don't go there.

Comment: You're in the right direction, and again half of the answer is correct!

Answer (score 1):

Could it be:

> Man Kind

It starts off as a creation of God,

> Man was created by God

followed by a godly creation.

> Kindness we would hope is a godly quality.

Having them together is odd,

> Finding a kind man is often a rarity anymore.

but between them is a one way affection.

> Men love kindness, but tend to not love to be kind.

A disgusting symbol of disparity
 between wealth and poverty.

> We are often most kind to those that are "*below*" us, or the poor. Sometimes that kindness is almost mocking.

Yet it is an irony
 as a proof of gender equality.

> One could argue that men are kind to women as a form of appeasing them, or trying to make up for different inequalities.

Comment: Everything fits surprisingly well except the 'godly creation'!  As a hint, you guys on SE have higher moral standard than I do